# Python: how to import a bunch of similar names?

Tags: python, import

I have a bunch of functions defined in file `foo.py`, each of them has the name like `func_xxx`. I want import only those functions, not the other things in `foo.py`. How can I achieve that without list them all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to define `__all__` inside `foo.py`. You could do something like this.

```
__all__ = [f for f in globals().keys() if f.startswith('func_')]
```

Defining an `__all__` only helps if you want to import from `foo` using the `from foo import *` syntax. One caveat is that `__all__` needs to be defined at the *end* of the module i.e. *after* all the `func_` functions are defined.

EDIT: You can't do `__all__ = [f for f in globals() if f.startswith('func_')]` because it will raise an error that `globals()` is being changed during iteration.

Comment: Wouldn't that only do the importing if he uses the wildcard mechanism? i.e. 'import * from foo'. What if the list of methods changes?

Comment: @synthesizerpatel You're right. This only works for `from foo import *`. Since he wanted to import all functions that start with `func_`, I assumed he wanted to import them directly into local namespace. Because even if he defines the rest of the variables in `foo` as private (with a leading underscore), `import foo` still just imports everything and he can still access the *private* variables anyway.

Comment: @P.J.Hades I fixed an error and added a caveat. Please take a look at the updated version.

Answer (score 2):

You could import foo.py and then do what you want with the `func_*` with [`vars()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#vars):

```
import foo

for name,value in vars(foo).items():
    if name.startswith('func_'):
        # do what you want with value
```

If you need to bring them into your namespace [`__import__()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#__import__) could help you, but I never used it, and I wouldn't recommend it unless you really need it.

Comment: @Praveen: I think `vars()` is what the OP is really looking for, because if the he doesn't know the complete name of the `func_*` what's the point of having them in your namespace if you don't know how to call them? [Edit: but it seems I was wrong somehow wrong :) ]

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do a `from foo import func_*`, alas.

You should import them all by name explicitly to make the code more cleaner and readable.

Answer (score 0):

If all these `func_xxx` functions are similar and belong together, how about defining a dictionary:

```
func = {'aaa': func_aaa,
        'bbb': func_bbb, …}
```

and then importing just this dictionary:

```
from foo import func
```

and then call them this way:

```
func['aaa'](…)
```

Comment: please fix your python syntax. `func{'aaa'}  ` is just a syntax error

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do something like:

```
globals(0.update (dict ((key, value) for key, value in __import__("foo").__dict__.items() if key.startswith("func__")     ) )
```

Though I don't recomend it - just use several "from foo import func_"  statements is a more readable form.

Answer (score 0):

I think the more pythonic approach would be to convert foo to package, move bar_xxx to foo/bar.py and remove the 'bar' prefix from function names.

so this

```
from foo import bar_xxx
bar_xxx(...)
```

would become this:

```
from foo import bar
bar.xxx(...)
```